# Trying to fetch users from firebase database in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to fetch users from firebase database in swift, but I am getting an error `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key`. I don't think I did anything wrong because its not my first app. I able to fetch users before in other app in exactly same way. But its not working now. all necessary details are below. Please help and Thank you
Here is code

```
func fetchUsers() {
    Database.database().reference().child("Users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            print(snapshot)
            let user = Users()
            user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
            //print(user.Email ?? "")
            //print(user.Name ?? "")

        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Here is model :

```
import UIKit

class Users: NSObject {
    var Name : String?
    var Email : String?
}
```

Screenshot of database
[image]

Error in console

> ChatHub[2089:904743] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Email.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x182dd7d38 0x1822ec528 0x182dd7a00 0x1836e3780 0x18377fc0c 0x1048000d8 0x104800174 0x1048ac760 0x1048d7e40 0x105b0d49c 0x105b0d45c 0x105b12050 0x182d7ff20 0x182d7dafc 0x182c9e2d8 0x184b2ff84 0x18c24b880 0x104806a64 0x1827c256c)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should not name your instances/objects/variables with a capital letter at the beginning, see: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/202031/what-is-the-reason-for-using-lowercase-for-the-first-word-in-a-local-variable-e.

Going back to your issue, have you tried renaming your `Users`'s properties? Use `Struct` as much as possible, and need not to use class and subclass the `NSObject`, like so, for easy initialization. I suspect that your variable name for `Email` is the cause of your error.

```
struct Users {
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
}
```

New instance of `Users`:

```
let user = Users(name: "name here", email: "email here")
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: lowercase first word still getting the same error. and yes, email is the cause of error.  :(

Comment: Having you tried cleaning up your project? `CMD+Shift+K` and `CMD+Shift+AltOption+K`. If that didn't work, then try renaming that to `emailAddress`

Comment: I cleaned project like 10 times and changed to emailaddress still no luck

Answer (score 0):

In your `fetchUsers()` function, try this:

```
if let dictionary = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [String: AnyObject] {
    // your code
}
```